# How to use the minimal polynomial theorem for this block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials, block-matrices

Let $M$ be a matrix made up of two diagonal blocks: $M = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & D\\ \end{pmatrix}$
Prove that $M$ is diagonalizable if and only if A and D are diagonalizable.

I know I'd have to use the minimal polynomial theorem, I just learnt it with one diagonal matrix in the diagonal, so for some reason I can't think of a way to implement it here

Is the minimal polynomial equation $M_{min} = A_{min} * D_{min}$ ?
And after that can I say $A_{min} * D_{min} = 0$?

Comment: Well, the minimal polynomial of M is easy to determine here. Try it and add your progress to the question. But surely the result can also be proven without minimal polynomials. Are you required to do so?

Comment: I'm not required to do so, but I thought that'd be the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we assume that $A$ and $D$ are diagonalizable. Thus, let $S$ be a matrix with columns consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ so that $S^{-1} A S$ has diagonal form, and similarly $T$ so that $T^{-1} D T$ is diagonal.

Then by the laws of matrix multiplication, one can easily see that $$R:=\left(\begin{matrix}S &0\\ 0& T\end{matrix}\right)$$
does the same for $M$, i.e. $R^{-1} MR$ has diagonal form.

The other implication works similarly: Given a matrix $R$ that diagonalizes $M$, it can be written as consisting of four quadratic matrices $$ \left(\begin{matrix}S & ? \\ ?& T\end{matrix}\right).$$
But after matrix-multiplication with $M$, one realizes that the $?$-blocks in $R$ actually correspond to the $0$-blocks in $M$, so we can forget about them and decompose $R$ into the two matrices $S$ and $T$ that diagonalize $A$ and $D$.